# Distance of centre of an ellipse touching both the positive X and Y axes from origin when the ellipse is being rotated

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

If a horizontal ellipse touches the X-axis and Y-axis in the first quadrant, and this ellipse is rotated in anti-clockwise sense always touching the X-axis and Y-axis, till the ellipse becomes vertical for the first time , then why will always the centre of the ellipse be at a constant distance from the origin throughout the rotation?

Answer (score 1):

This is true because the locus of intersection points of orthogonal tangents to an ellipse is a circle (called orthoptic of the ellipse).
It is centered at the center of the ellipse, and its radius is $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}.$

See also 
         https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse#Tangent
or

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthoptic_(geometry)